# RxJava - Flowable.map not getting called after flatMap

Tags: java, rx-java2

I am having weird issue with the Flowable<T> vs Observable<T> in rxjava (io.reactivex.rxjava2 - v2.0.8). Here I have code that looks like below, where **map(...).subscribe(...)** functions are not getting called / executed.

```
flowable.flatMap(...return new flowable...).map(...).subscribe(...)
```

Surprisingly, if I flip my code to make use of Observable<T> instead of Flowable<T>, the **map(...).subscribe(...)** is getting called / executed as expected. I might be missing something simple, let me know what it could be?

Thank you

`

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        // Note: Working; get the list of databases
        DatabaseFlowable databases = new DatabaseFlowable(sourceClient);
        // Note: Working; for each database get the list of collections in it
        Flowable<Resource> resources = databases
            .flatMap(db -> {
                logger.info(" ==> found database {}", db.getString("name"));
                return new CollectionFlowable(sourceClient, db.getString("name"));
                // Note: Working; CollectionFlowable::subscribeActual works as well
            });
        resources
            .map(resource -> {
                // Note: Nothing in here gets executed
                logger.info(" ====> found resource {}", resource.toString());
                return resource;
            })
            .subscribe(m -> {
                // Note: Nothing in here gets executed
                logger.info(m.toString());
            });
    }
}



public class DatabaseFlowable extends Flowable<Document> {
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseFlowable.class);
    private final MongoClient client;

    public DatabaseFlowable(MongoClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Subscriber<? super Document> subscriber) {
        ListDatabasesIterable<Document> cursor = client.listDatabases();
        MongoCursor<Document> iterator = cursor.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Document item = iterator.next();
            if (!item.isEmpty()) {
                    String message = String.format(" found database name: %s, sizeOnDisk: %s",
                            item.getString("name"), item.get("sizeOnDisk"));
                    logger.info(message);
                    subscriber.onNext(item);
            }
        }
        subscriber.onComplete();
    }
}

public class CollectionFlowable extends Flowable<Resource> {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CollectionFlowable.class);
    private final MongoClient client;
    private final String databaseName;

    public CollectionFlowable(MongoClient client, String databaseName) {
        this.databaseName = databaseName;
        this.client = client;
    }


    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Subscriber<? super Resource> subscriber) {
        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase(databaseName);

        ListCollectionsIterable<Document> cursor = database.listCollections();
        MongoCursor<Document> iterator = cursor.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Document item = iterator.next();
            if (!item.isEmpty()) {
                logger.info(" ... found collection: {}.{}", database.getName(), item.getString("name"));
                Resource resource = new Resource(databaseName,
                        item.getString("name"),
                        (Document) item.get("options"));
                subscriber.onNext(resource);
            }
        }
        subscriber.onComplete();
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not correctly following the `Flowable` protocol. There is no call to `subscriber.onSubscribe(...)` and it does not observe the limit imposed by `subscriber.request(...)`.

Since your implementation in no way observes backpressure, either use `Flowable.create` to create a buffered version that does or move your implementation to `Observable` which is not backpressured.

The reason for the behavior you see is that the downstream observer has not requested any items, so your calls to `onNext` are discarded.

Comment: I agree that I might not be using the Flowables properly. Could you please help suggest what should I change or give some pointers to an example that might shed more light. Thank you

Comment: All your custom `Flowables` can essentially be replaced by `Flowable.create(...)` implementations. If you use the BUFFER backpressure strategy then no emissions should be lost.